# VoiceOver reads content of aria-live in system language (en), even with lang="nl" applied. How to change?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, aria-live

I have a live region on my page. The whole page is in dutch (`lang="nl"` on `<html>` is applied), and for most text, it all works fine. However, if I use a live region with `aria-live`, the text is announced in the system language, even if I put `lang="nl"` on the live region itself.

Is this a bug in VoiceOver? Or do I do something wrong?

I made a codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/petergoes/pen/LYbagMw

The code:

```html
<div lang="nl">
    <span id="output" aria-live="polite"></span>
</div>

<button id="fill-en">Add English text</button>
<button id="fill-nl">Add Dutch text</button>
```

```js
const enText = "This is some text in English"
const nlText = "Dit is wat tekst in het Nederlands"
const $enButton = document.querySelector('#fill-en')
const $nlButton = document.querySelector('#fill-nl')
const $output = document.querySelector('#output')

$enButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $output.lang = 'en'
    $output.innerText = enText
})

$nlButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $output.lang = 'nl'
    $output.innerText = nlText
})
```